# Guinea Bissau national transiting in Morocco

Tags: transit-visas, morocco

I'm a Guinea Bissau national flying with Air Maroc from Bissau and then connecting with Emirates to Dubai. Do I need a transit visa since I will have to check in my luggage while connecting with Emirates?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a transit visa, as your two carriers, Air Maroc and Emirates, are not partner airlines and you would have to collect and re-check your baggage for your onward flight.

According to Timatic, the tool used by airlines to check document requirements (and courtesy of [Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=GW&NV=Guinea-Bissau&DC=AE&DV=United%20Arab%20Emirates&TC=MA&TV=Morocco&h=cd2d61d7938f1b932aa3cb31f2f9d41d950ff6d)):

**Transit - Morocco (MA)** Visa required.
**Visa Exemptions:** TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country on the same calendar day. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

Resources:

- [Visas and entry conditions in Morocco](https://www.aeroportdecasablanca.com/visa_on_arrival_morocco.php)
- [Morocco Embassy/Consulate serving Guinea Bissau](https://www.diplomatie.ma/en/Corpsdiplomatiquesetconsulaires.aspx?pays=GUINEA%20BISSAU&id_pays=123): 
  Ambassadeur non Resident
  القائم بالأعمال : M. Armando Albino Arafǎ
  Rue 6, Angle B Point E - Dakar - Sénégal
  Téléphone : 824 59 22
  Fax : 824 59 22